# Link the position of two divs inside and outside of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have an iframe and many divs in it. Now I want to create a box for a hint that is linked to a particular div within the iframe, i.e. is on the same height and moves with the iframe div when I scroll in the iframe. Is there any way to achieve this?

Note that I cannot move the hint into the iframe because the content is generated generically and there's no space for hints.

The concept:

```
_______________________
|  ___________________ |  ____________ 
| |                   || |  hint div  |
| |      div          || |____________|
| |___________________||
|                      |
|        iframe        |
|                      |
|______________________|
```

Thanks

Comment: It would appear that permitting such a thing would be a security risk...  iframe content should not be permitted to communicate with the containing frame/window

Comment: Do the content of the iframe and the page on which the iframe is coded originate from the same domain?

Comment: Yes, both pages are in the same domain.
@PinnyM I thought maybe the parent window could follow the scroll position somehow without the iframe having to communicate with it.

Comment: No, the iframe shouldn't know this.  However, if you are using the same domain, why bother with an iframe?  After all, it appears that you have JS enabled and can use AJAX to load this content into a div.

Comment: as mentioned why? the iFrame if they reside in the same domain, why not use ajax/jquery etc to load the content into a specified div that way you have total control on the dom of all

Comment: I am not familiar with AJAX. I tried to load the content using   `$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#viewer").load(url);
  });` but it didn't work.

Comment: make sure `#viewer` refer to a div and not an iframe. (as it would defeat the purpose..)

Comment: Wrap the `#hint_div`(`position: absolute`) and `iframe` within a `#wrapper` div (`position: relative`). Then in `iframe`, add an onscroll event listener for `window`, and in that handler function read `#div`'s `getBoundingClientRect().top` value, and set the value to `#hint_div`'s `style.top`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the contentWindow of the iframe with `iframe.contentWindow`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp

Then you'll need to do some calculations based on the scroll (`iframe.contentWindow.documentElement.scrollTop || iframe.contentWindow.body.scrollTop`)

and the div position (`iframe.contentWindow.getElementById("divID").offsetTop`)

Note that this is only available for non cross-domain.

And overall - AJAX is more reccommended than iframes. see http://rev.iew.me/help-moving-from-iframes